# Subs object still remains after calling doit method in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to calculate general composite function derivative using sympy. In my specific case script is the following:

```
from sympy import *
t=symbols('t')
p=Function('p')
x=Function('x')
v=diff(x(p(t)),t)
a=diff(v,t)
```

for variable `a` it yields:

```
Derivative(p(t), t)**2*Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t), p(t)) + Derivative(p(t), t, t)*Subs(Derivative(x(_xi_1), _xi_1), (_xi_1,), (p(t),))
```

If I call `doit()`, answer still contains subs object

```
a.doit() #answer: Derivative(p(t), t)**2*Subs(Derivative(x(_xi_3), _xi_3, _xi_3), (_xi_3,), (p(t),)) + Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t))*Derivative(p(t), t, t)
```

Mathematically the answer is correct but I still need output in following format (without Subs objects):

```
Derivative(p(t), t)**2*Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t), p(t)) + Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t))*Derivative(p(t), t, t)
```

Is there any way to achieve desired result? To be clear this example is very simplified compared to my original expression so I need general way to get desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, repeated applications of `doit()` in this case result in flip-flopping between two forms of the expression: half the time the first addend has Subs, half the time it's the second.

But you can deal with the issue as follows:

```
for b in a.atoms(Subs):
  a = a.xreplace({b: b.doit()})
```

This returns `Derivative(p(t), t)**2*Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t), p(t)) + Derivative(x(p(t)), p(t))*Derivative(p(t), t, t)` as desired.

The trick is that `atoms(Subs)` is the set of all Subs objects in the expression, and doit is applied only to them, not to Derivative objects where it only messes things up. (Ideally, `doit` would not mess Derivative objects up in the first place...)

Comment: [Relevant issue in SymPy repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11737)